# Unity - Background Music through scenes with UI slider

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio, uislider, mixer

I created a game in Unity with 4 different scenes (start, login, options, game itself).

With an empty game object (in the start scene) and the `DontDestroyOnLoad` function I have managed to have the music played throughout all scenes without stopping or loading new in every scene.

In the options scene there is a slider hooked to an master audio mixer, which works so far.

The only problem for me is that the slider can "interfere" with the `gameobject` in the start scene (background music, which should be triggered through the slider).
It would be awesome if someone could help me! :)

Here some extracts:

`ChangeVolume` class:

```
public AudioMixer audioMixer;

public void setVolume(float volume){
    audioMixer.SetFloat ("volume", volume);
}
```

and

`MusicBehaviour` class:

```
//Play global
private static MusicBehaviour instance = null;
    public static MusicBehaviour Instance {
        get {
              return instance;
        }
    }

void Awake()
{
    if (instance != null && instance != this) {
        Destroy (this.gameObject);
        return;
    } else {
        instance = this;
    }
    DontDestroyOnLoad (this.gameObject);
}

//Play Global End

//Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
}
```

I'm excited for your help/solutions, maybe there is a simpler one! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest approach is to use `PlayerPrefs` and save the sound value there. Every time you start the game in `Awake()` you will setup the value and when slider is triggered you change the value in `PlayerPrefs` and set it to the `MusicBehaviour` instance.

Comment: I never thought about PlayerPrefs, but i think i get it. Maybe it's even better than my solution but:
If anyone is interested, I'll post my solution below. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem through editing my scripts in the following way:

`Music Behaviour` class:

```
 void Update () {
         float vol = ChangeVolume.vol;
         this.gameObject.GetComponent<AudioSource> ().volume = vol;
     }
```

`Change Volume` class:

```
public void setVolume(float volume){
    vol = volume;
}

public static float vol = 1.0f;
```

I also deleted my audiomixer due to not needing it anymore. And it works just fine! :-)